# highcharts has no exported member 'ChartObject'

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I want to setup highcharts for my angular 4 project but i keep on getting this error:

```
highcharts has no exported member 'ChartObject'
```

I have tried,
angular-highcharts,
highcharts-angualr,
ng2-highcharts,

```
import { chart } from 'highcharts';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting.. and what you have tried..?

Comment: @ganesh045 The error is in the title

Comment: Have you added `ChartModule` from angular-highcharts in your app.module.ts file? Please check this [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts).

Comment: i have done these steps still i have error as no exported member 'ChartObject'

Comment: @jess yes i have done that step and also my angular version is 4 and that documentation states that it should be greater than 6

Comment: Therefore, it is not supported. Try to update your code to Angular 6 then.

Comment: i was looking for a workaround in angular 4 as the code is quite large and would require intensive testing if it is to be upgraded @jess thanks! bye the way

Comment: @ganesh045 the error is mentioned above.

Comment: @jess that's not related. This is a typescript error. He needs `@types/highcharts`

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like codesandbox?

Comment: @AluanHaddad yeah i have done that also still no luck.

Comment: Same here after upgrading to version 8 and removing `@types/highcharts`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Chart` type instead of `ChartObject`.

```
import * as highcharts from 'highcharts';

const myChart: highcharts.Chart;

myChart = hightcharts.chart(someElement, {
...
});
```